# What RegEx will extract my links?

Tags: python, regex

I have several python strings that look like this:

```
s = '  text before [[my.fake.web.address.com][link text]] text after   '
```

I am trying to write a function that replaces the `[[my.fake.web.address.com][link text]]` with an html link `<a href="my.fake.web.address.com">link text</a>`. To do so, I'd like a function that breaks my string into a list

```
>>> myfunc(s)
['  text before ', 'my.fake.web.address.com', 'link text', ' text after   ']
```

The function I'm using now is

```
def myfunc(s):
    before, rest = s.split('[[')
    address, rest = rest.split('][')
    linktext, after = rest.split(']]')
    return [before, address, linktext, after]
```

I'm curious if there is a better way to do this. Is there a RegEx solution that would be more efficient?

Comment: More efficient for legibility, probably. For computational efficiency, regex is probably not the right answer.

Answer (score 4):

If your text doesn't contain `[[]]` except for those which wrap the address and link text, you can use `\[\[(.*?)\]\[(.*?)\]\]`, and insert the link tag into the string with back reference:

```
import re
re.sub('\[\[(.*?)\]\[(.*?)\]\]', r'<a href="\1">\2</a>', s)

# '  text before <a href="my.fake.web.address.com">link text</a> text after   '
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import re
s = '  text before [[my.fake.web.address.com][link text]] text after   '
#<a href="my.fake.web.address.com">link text</a>
tag = re.sub(r'\[\[(.+?)\]\[(.+?)\]\]', r'<a href="\1">\2</a>', s)
```

out:

```
 text before <a href="my.fake.web.address.com">link text</a> text after
```

If you want to reuse the text in the sub, you should use capture

> (...)
>
> Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, and
>   indicates the start and end of a group; the contents of a group can be
>   retrieved after a match has been performed, **and can be matched later
>   in the string with the \number special sequenc**e, described below.

And make sure you escapt the key word in the regex using `'\'`, like `\[\]` to match real `[]`.

Comment: @Brian Fitzpatrick please accept an answer to close this question, this will save other people's time.

Answer (score 3):

To replace the fake link `[[my.fake.web.address.com][link text]]` with
 `<a href="my.fake.web.address.com">link text</a>`

I would use:

```
result = re.sub(r"\[\[([^]]+)]\[([^]]+)]]", r'<a href="\1">\2</a>', subject)
```

Note that the `]` does not need to be escaped.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it

```
import re
mt = re.compile(r'.*\[\[(?P<www>.*)\]\[(?P<text>.*)\]\].*')
m = mt.match(s).groupdict()
output = '<a ref="{0}">{1}</a>'.format(m['www'], m['text'])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

def getRegex(s, reg = ".\[\[(.+)\]\["):
    m = re.search(reg, s)
    return m.group(1)

s = "  text before [[my.fake.web.address.com][link text]] text after   "
print getRegex(s);
```

Check this out!

EDIT: Sorry for being dumb, I guess you asked for this.

```
def changeLinks(s, replStr = r'<a href="http://\1">\2</a>', reg = "\[\[(.+)\]\[(.+)\]\]"):
    r = re.sub(reg, replStr, s)
    return r

# text before <a href="http://my.fake.web.address.com">link text</a> 
print changeLinks(s);
```

Cheers,
Rj